# How can you add custom metadata to a video (.mov, .mp4) with AVFoundation?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation

Although this question has been asked before, I still have not found a single working example of how to do this.

I have a golf swing analysis app that allows the user to save 10 positions in the videoclip that can be navigated to with a shortcut. Until now I have saved the position data separately from the video-file, which is less than ideal for obvious reasons, so I would like to save the position data as metadata in the video-file.

Can anyone give me a working example of saving a String (I'll use `Codable` to encode the data structure which is not very large) to a custom metadata key (ex. "posi") given an `AVAsset`?

Comment: Have you looked at `AVAssetWriterInputMetadataAdaptor` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinputmetadataadaptor ?

Comment: That's for timed metadata. I want to add a json-encoded struct that contains all my bookmarks.

Comment: If you add the data once at an early timestamp isn’t it the same thing?